# Export project from Paw Cloud

Tags: paw-app

I used the super easy migration to Paw Cloud for one of my .paw files. Now I don't want to have it in the cloud anymore, but cannot find any way to migrate back to a normal local .paw file on disk.

How do I export a project from Paw Cloud to a local .paw file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the export flow is still not exactly great yet. But here's what you can do for now:

- Go to your admin dashboard => projects: https://paw.cloud/account/projects
- Pick the project you want, and in the "Danger Zone", hit "Delete Project" (your project will be deleted from Paw Cloud, but the file will be left on disk)
- Go back to Paw, and play around with the project. As soon as the server is hit, Paw will inform you that the cloud project has been deleted, and will offer you to export your data back to a file

I hope it helps, and sorry for the bad UX.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this now? This [doc](https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments) mentions a `.paw` file as well which contains the environment. But not sure how to produce this file.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I export a project from Paw Cloud to a local .paw file?

To answer this question:

1. On Mac you can click on File > Save as Document:

[image: Click file then Save as Document...]

2. Then you'll be able to save your project as `.paw`

[image: The extension of your saved file will be .paw]

Hope this helps!